# can not execute servlet code

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

while developing servlet program i suffered from a probem i used netbeans ide and used glassfish server
here is my code for the index.html file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="NewServlet">
            name:<input type="text" name="t1">
            password:<input type="password" name="t1">
            <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and code for servlet is:-

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Prathamesh
 */
public class NewServlet extends GenericServlet {
    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        String un="abc";
        String pwd="xyz";
        String p1=req.getParameter("t1");
        String p2=req.getParameter("t2");
        if((p1.equals(un))&&(p2.equals(pwd)))
            pw.println("<h1>Welcome to home page</h1>");
        else
            pw.println("Invalid");
        pw.close();    
    }
}
```

i think the problem is occuring while parsing the variables is servlet...
please any one can help me??
and also the index file executes perfectly but when i directly click on button without typing anything in textbox it shows correct output but when i enter username and password specified in programs(abc & xyz) it shows error:

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that you failed to pass correct name to password field:

```
password:<input type="password" name="t1">
```

In servlet, you used the code, which returns `p2` as `null`

```
String p2=req.getParameter("t2");

p2.equals(pwd)//results in NPE
```

Try this in html

```
password:<input type="password" name="t2">
```

Comment: thanks for the help...sorry for my childish mistake...and now it is running perfectly

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti, kindly accept the answer as it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

`GenericServlet` is for protocol-independent servlet. For Web, use `HttpServlet`. So, you should extends `HttpServlet` instead of `GenericServlet` and override `doGet` or `doPost` method. As you have password field so override `doPost` method, which is recommended for security reason. Than configure servlet at `web.xml` or use `@WebServlet` annotation

```
@WebServlet
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet{
   public void doPost(...){}
}
```

At form you need to define `post` method

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
      ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You HTML can not distinguish between `name = t1`for Name and `name="t1"` for password. Try changing it to `t1` and `t2`. In your code you are not sending any `t2` to the servlet. Also try to use HttpServlet instead GenericServlet.